# Storyboard.begin crash - Cannot resolve all property references in the property path FrameworkElement.Margin

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard, margin

I am using a Storyboard in code, so I can dynamically animate a button, but my code crashes at Storyboard.begin(); throwing an exception called InvalidOperationException (detailed ErrorMessage in title). I googled it but I cannot use their solutions in my code.

So what I want to do is to move a button to the position of the textbox that was clicked.

```
private void btnFunktionX_MouseDoubleClick(object sender,      MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
        string textboxnumber =     (((System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender).Name)    [(((System.Windows.Controls.Button)sender).Name).Length - 1].ToString();
        Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();

        ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames tauk = new ThicknessAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        tauk.BeginTime = new TimeSpan(0);
        tauk.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetNameProperty, "btnFunktion"+textboxnumber);
        tauk.SetValue(Storyboard.TargetPropertyProperty, new PropertyPath("FrameworkElement.Margin"));
        EasingThicknessKeyFrame easing = new EasingThicknessKeyFrame();

        easing.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2);
        easing.Value = Usedmargin[chosentextbox];
        tauk.KeyFrames.Add(easing);
        sb.Children.Add(tauk);
        sb.Begin(this);
    }
```

Usedmargin is a Thickness Array which gets all the relevant Margins at program start.

Comment: Try `new PopertyPath("Margin")`. And is there any reason why you're not using the `Storyboard.SetTargetName()` and `Storyboard.SetTargetProperty()` methods, and instead call `SetValue()`?

Comment: And if you want to animate the Button that was clicked, call `Storyboard.SetTarget(tauk, (Button)sender)` instead of fiddling around with the Button's Name.

Comment: Finally, "a Thickness Array [with the] relevant Margins" looks odd. You should probably use a proper layout panel instead of positioning elements by their Margins.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I implemented everything you said in the first 2 comments, but I dont understand how I should get the positions of the textboxes without using their margins. Please guide me into the direction of doing this the right way. @Clemens

Comment: Use an appropriate layout Panel, e.g. a Grid or a StackPanel.

Comment: They already are in a Grid, but even so I do not understand how that changes my approach to move my object from its position to the position of another object, since their position is still defined by their margins right?  @Clemens

Comment: Usually the positions of elements in a Grid are specified by their `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` indices, after you have defined a set of Grid rows and columns. Take a look at the online documentation.